# Android date-time manipulation library

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

Coming from C#, I got used to the slick interface [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offer. With these, I can access date-time parts (Year, Month, Seconds, etc.), the underlying Ticks, subtract dates, add time deltas and so on.

As a Java/Android newbie, I understand that the equivalent Java [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class used to have these accessors, but they were removed for back-compatibility reasons. The suggested alternative is to use a [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29) object, but I find its interface cumbersome compared with .Net's.

Is there an equivalent Java library to ease the manipulation of `Date` objects in Android?

Comment: I think you should stick to calendar even if it's not very pretty to write or read. Some android objects like datePicker, TimePicker, ... are using Calendar, so using this one might ease the use of android components in the future

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 raises a good point; you should consider your application when thinking about using third-party libraries. That said, Joda is kind of the de facto alternative to Java's built in date/time API when you need more than what the JDK provides; and conversions to/from `Calendar` are generally straightforward via Joda object constructors and/or intermediate conversion to epoch time integers.

Comment: Also, all that said, Java 8 (just released a couple of days ago, incidentally) has a [new date/time API](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/24-a-new-date-and-time-api-for-jdk-8) ([official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)), although it may be a while before Android sees Java 8 support.

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 You can easily translate between java.util.Date and Joda-Time. `java.util.Date date = myDateTime.toDate();` and `DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime( date, timeZone );`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

As @basil pointed out in the comment below

> The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. Its creator, Stephen Colebourne, went on to lead JSR 310 defining the java.time classes built into Java 8+. See Tutorial by Oracle. – Basil Bourque 1 min ago

you can use [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) it is an external library, Date & Calendar are basic API provided, with java 8 it has added much better api for date time but for android for now you can use joda tiem

Comment: Joda-Time offers three classes for representing a span of time: Interval, Duration, and Period.

Comment: Update: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 11):

## java.time

The other Answers are outdated.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework is a highly successful and brilliant piece of work. However, its creators led by [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen) did a complete rewrite and redesign to produce the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. That work is further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Joda-Time continues to be maintained. But the team has advised that we migrate to java.time as soon as is convenient. Future innovation work will go into java.time and its extension in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

I suggest dabbling with java.time in your fresh code. No need to delete Joda-Time. Both frameworks can coexist in your projects. Just be careful with your `import` statements as a few of the classes share a name between both frameworks. Later, once you are comfortable with java.time, you can think about revisiting old code to phase out use of Joda-Time.

### `ZonedDateTime`

See the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. It has the methods you ask for, `getYear`, `getHour`, and such.

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in UTC resolving to nanoseconds (finer than the milliseconds and microseconds used in other libraries/systems). This is the basic-building class of *java.time*.

> I can access date-time parts (Year, Month, Seconds, etc.), the underlying Ticks, subtract dates, add time deltas and so on.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
int year = zdt.getYear() ;
int hour = zdt.getHour() ;
int second = zdt.getSecond() ;
long millisecondsSinceEpochOfFirstMomentOf1970InUtc = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
ZonedDateTime earlier = zdt.minusDays( 3 ) ;  // Three days prior.
Duration duration = Duration.of( earlier , zdt ) ;  // Scale of 24-hour days (not attached to the calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and fraction of second.
Period period = Period.of( earlier.toLocalDate() , zdt.toLocalDate() ) ;  // Scale of year-months-days.
```

### Spans of time

For spans of time not attached to the timeline, see the `Period` and `Duration` classes. The various date-time classes have math methods for adding or subtracting such objects.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: `java.time` is not available before Android API level 26, which excludes its use from all but the most up-to-date devices.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I addressed that in my third paragraph. And now I added the "About *java.time*" section with a table-graphic to explain more about how to use *java.time* functionality on Android.

Comment: What an answer! Thanks to you this mess starts to make a little bit of sense ;-)

Comment: Great answer, should be accepted IMHO. Special thanks for pointing out the Java Desugaring library, saved my day!

Comment: Thanks! For Android API < 26, the only simple way to correctly set a date is apparently with *API desugaring*. Using `Date(121, 7, 30)` or `cal = Calendar.getInstance()` then `cal.set(2021, 7, 30)` will only give unreliable results.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using this library instead of Joda:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

The reasons are written there:

> Why not use Joda-Time? Joda-Time has a very large API which brings
>   with it a very large binary size and large method count. The creator
>   of both JSR-310 and Joda-Time has also said that while Joda-Time isn't
>   broken, it does have design flaws.
>
> If you are using Joda-Time already, there's little reason to switch
>   unless its size or method count is relevant to you. For new projects,
>   however, this library offers the standard APIs in Java 8 as a much
>   smaller package in not only binary size and method count, but also in
>   API size.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to provide a more updated answer.

There is also [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) "a version of Joda-Time built with Android in mind". [Jake Wharton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God) has his own library [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). You might want to check it out.

Comment: Coming back here many years later I realized that Basil's answer is better and way more complete...

Answer (score 0):

Improving on the answer of Jigar Joshi, you can use [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android), an android specific port of joda-time which is optimized for android devices.