# How to get the time zone offset in android>

Tags: android, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

How do I get the timezone offset in android - java?
an error in local date-time appears.

```
 public static String getOffsetTimeZone() {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Timber.e(": %s", timeZone.getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));
    Timber.e(" timeZone.getID(): %s", timeZone.getID());

    String myTimeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault().getId();
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDate dt0 = LocalDate.now(); // Added 1.8


    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(myTimeZone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
    ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
    int secondsOfHour = offset.getTotalSeconds() % (60 * 60);
    String out = String.format("%35s %10s%n"," zone= "+ zone," offset= "+ offset);
    Timber.e("out= " + out);
    return "UTC";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the following to get it. This will get you your current offset.

```java
Integer offset  = ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```java
ZoneId
.systemDefault()
.getRules()
.getOffset(
    Instant.now()
)
```

## Details

Never use `TimeZone`. That class is one of the legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never call `LocalDateTime.now()`. That class cannot represent a moment as it purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset from UTC. I cannot imagine a scenario where calling that method would be the right thing to do.

Get your JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Get the rules for that zone, the history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of that particular region.

```
ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules() ;
```

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Get the offset in effect at that moment in that zone, producing a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( instant ) ;
```

The *java.time* classes are present in Android 26 and later. For earlier Android, modern tooling provides most of the functionality via “API desugaring”.

Comment: Thanks, bro, how could I support API < Build.VERSION_CODES.O. in this code?

Comment: @AnwarBaniAmer See end of my Answer.

Comment: [Android - Date in API Level 21 \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687806/android-date-in-api-level-21)